# PHP Regular expression to create an array

Tags: php, regex

I have a string which is pulled from iCal, which outputs the description. I want to take the description each time and create an array with the objects I need. They always follow the same pattern.

For example I have:

```
Description: Trip status: Confirmed\n \n FLIGHT INFORMATION: \n \n United Airlines UA 485: \n \n \n From: Newark Liberty International (New York, USA) - TerminalC at Fri, Sep 28, 2012 16:34 (local time) \n To: Denver International (Denver, USA) at Fri, Sep 28, 2012 18:47 (local time) \n Cabin: Economy Restricted\n Duration: 04:13\n Stop(s): 0\n Aircraft: Boeing 757-200\n
```

and then

```
Description: Trip status: Confirmed\n \n FLIGHT INFORMATION: \n \n Air Canada AC 1072: \n \n \n From: Denver International (Denver, USA) at Sat, Sep 29, 2012 10:55 (local time) \n To: P Trudeau International (Montreal, Canada) at Sat, Sep 29, 2012 16:29 (local time) \n Cabin: Economy Restricted\n Duration: 03:34\n Stop(s): 0\n Aircraft: Airbus Industrie A319\n
```

As you can see the different outputs follow the same structure, so in an ideal world I would want:

```
$itinery[0]: Confirmed
$itinery[1]: United Airlines UA 485
$itinery[2]: Newark Liberty International (New York, USA)
```

Any guidance as ever is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I did do explode given that there is an instance of: "\n" then also "\n \n" and later on "\n \n \n" - so I have to then cleanse each array element. I wondered if there was an easier way to achieve this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more specific regex :

> Description:\s*Trip\s+status:\s+(\w+)\s*FLIGHT\s+INFORMATION:\s*([^:]+):\s*From:\s*([\w\d_,\s-()]+)\s+at\s+(?:Sun|Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat),

Following assumptions are made :

- The "status" can contain only letters.
- The "flight information" is supposed to end with a `:`
- The "from" can contain only letters, numbers, one of those characters `_,-()` or blank characters. The "from" is immediately followed by this sequence : " at XXX" where XXX is a day (ie Sun,Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri or Sat).

**Tips :**
If status belongs to a closed list then replace `(\w+)` with `(?:Confirmed|Cancelled|Delayed)` in the regex. Add other statuses if necessary.

Comment: Thanks Stephan.. how do I code this within php to generate an array?

Comment: Use the [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.preg-match-all.php) function. Since I have already give you the most difficult part, I leave you as an exercice the final PHP code ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could also break each line apart with explode()

```
$parts = explode ( $line, '\n' ) ;
print_r ( $parts ) ;
```

Then break the parts with explode ( $part[$i], ':' ) to get the values.